# Let non-admin backend users change their own password

Tags: security, password

I have a shop with multiple users, some of them with quite restricted rights (handling orders only).
I have however not found a solution to let them change their own password without involving an admin or giving them the rights to change all users in the shop.
Is there a way to achieve a way to let non-admin users set their own password (possibly also with password guidelines, but this is not necessary) without involving another party?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure that anybody with access to the backend can change their own password via `System > My Account`. There is a field for `Current Admin Password` which uses the word admin, but it just means the current logged in user. The user just needs the acl `system/myaccount`, which should only give them the ability to change their own information.

Comment: Oh okay, I always misinterpreted the wording and obviously so did all other users. Thanks for the headsup, this is the solution I was looking for.

Still, password guidelines would be a nice to have.